# Reference document fields in collection of embedded documents in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to merge two array fields, located in a collection of embedded documents, in an pipeline stage. But I'm stuck on how to reference the two "*internal*" arrays of the embedded document.

### The collection

```
[{
    name: "first",
    docs: [
        { a1: ["a", "b"], a2: ["c"] },
        { a1: ["d", "e"], a2: ["f"] }
    ]
},
{
    name: "second",
    docs: [
        { a1: [1, 2], a2: [3] },
        { a1: [4, 5], a2: [6] }
    ]
}]
```

### Expected result

```
[{
    name: "first",
    docs: [
        { merged: ["a", "b", "c"] },
        { merged: ["d", "e", "f"] }
    ]
},
{
    name: "second",
    docs: [
        { merged: [1, 2, 3] },
        { merged: [4, 5, 6] }
    ]
}]
```

### Approach

The overall approach I tried so far is:
*(with 2 hard-coded arrays for testing purposes)*

```
db.getCollection("collection").aggregate([{
    $set: {
         "docs.merged": {
             $concatArrays: [["hello"], ["world"]]
         }
    }
}])
```

Which yields the expected results:

```
[{
    name : "first",
    docs : [
        {
            a1 : ["a", "b"],
            a2 : ["c"],
            merged : ["hello", "world"] // <- OK
        },
        {
            a1 : ["d", "e"],
            a2 : ["f"],
            merged : ["hello", "world"] // <- OK
        }
    ]
},{
    name : "second",
    docs : [
        {
            a1 : [1.0, 2.0],
            a2 : [3.0],
            merged : ["hello", "world"] // <- OK
        },
        {
            a1 : [4.0, 5.0],
            a2 : [6.0],
            merged : ["hello", "world"] // <- OK
        }
    ]
}]
```

But I'm having difficulties grasping how to reference the fields in the *current* embedded document:

```
// Using the "$" reference causes following error:
// Invalid $set :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.
{
    $set: {
         "docs.merged": { $concatArrays: ["$docs.$.a1", "$docs.$.a2"] }
    }
}

// $$this is only available with a MAP operator
{
    $set: {
         "docs.merged": { $concatArrays: ["$$this.a1", "$$this.a2"] }
    }
}
```

### Considerations

I cannot use an `update` query, as the original documents must not be altered. So this **must** be achieved within a `aggregate` pipeline.

I try to avoid using `unwind` operations at this point, as this will have a significant performance impact. The *actual* documents contains quite a lot of (variable) fields at it's root; making a `group` stage after the `unwind` quite complex.
*(The example has been greatly simplified for readability)*

I'm using MongoDB `v4.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do it, please let me know if there's anything I'm missing:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
   $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "name": 1,
      "docs": {
         $function: {
            body: function(docs) {
              docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                 var merged = [];
                 Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(k) {
                    merged = merged.concat(doc[k]);
                    delete doc[k];
                 });
                 doc.merged = merged;
              });
              return docs;
            },
            args: [ "$docs" ],
            lang: "js"
         }
      }
   }
}])
```

Comment: I expected it to be solvable with build-in functionality. But the ```$function``` operator solved this perfectly with acceptable performance impact. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like following.

1. First `$unwind` to flat the docs array.
2. Since a1 and a2 are dynamic, we make this into array. (Multiple dynamic keys can be constructed your output if we use this).
3. Then `$reduce` to add data into array.
4. And regroup it to get desired output.

The aggregation script is

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": "$docs"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      data: {
        $objectToArray: "$docs"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      data: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$this.v",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      docs: {
        $push: {
          merged: "$data"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NgfIjmO7VuT)**

Comment: I try to avoid ```unwind``` as this would force me to regroup the documents. This is more complex as my actual documents contain lots of (variable) properties at it's root.
The question was more about how to reference fields in the embedded document.

Comment: I tried in different way too, But I feel anyhow you need to use group. But you can group it by `$$ROOT` and replace by the data. But I'm eagerly waiting for someone reply who doesn't use unwind and group

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) could help with this - since you're using MongoDB v4.4+.